# Integrate Angular schematics into Nx monorepo

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have an Angular schematic that I want to integrate to my Nx workspace. Calling the ng-add generator of the schematic on an existing Nx app like `nx add @SCHEMATICNAME:ng-add` fails with a message telling that Angular Material can only be used in default configurations. I want to be able to generate apps just like how I would do with `nx g app NAME`, but have it utilize my schematics. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ki2eOXvh2Sw) was exceptionally helpful for me to achieve this task. I recommend watching it. I ended up copying the files from the Angular schematic directly from `node_modules` and putting other necessary files in a folder, and making Json updates from inside the script.